# How to modify MySQL column to set CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on insert and do nothing on update?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `admin_members` (
  `admin_id` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `joined_on` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `admin_email` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `admin_password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `admin_name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `admin_id` (`admin_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I would like the joined_on field to automatically set to CURRENT_TIMEZONE on insert as the default value and do nothing on update. How can I update the table to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below syntax to just update on creation but not updation.

```
`joined_on` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

You can use below syntax if want to update in both scenario:

```
`joined_on` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```